# javascript, substring should exclude html tags in its character count

Tags: javascript, substring

The substr should not consider html tags in its count, is there any way to achieve it?

for example, if I have

```
 input =  <p> This is testing <strong> hi </strong> how are you, Well doing  </p>
```

The `input.substring(0, 20)` should not consider `<p>` and `<strong>` tags in its character count.

The html tags should not be removed from the string, just they have to be ignore in the count for substring.

```
     <h2 v-html="this.$options.filters.limitText(input)" ></h2>

     filters: {
      limitText: function (val) {
       if(val && (val.length > 20)) {
         return (val.substring(0, 20).replace(/\s\S*$/, '') + ' ...')
       }
      return val;
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just wondering if you have access to a DOM to solve this problem.  You could assign it to an HTMLElement and then using HTMLElement.innerText to strip off the tags, then get the length of what remains.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
const input = "<p> This is testing <strong> hi </strong> how are you, Well doing  </p>";
const tags = /<[^>]*>/g;
const output = input.replace(tags, '').substring(0, 20);
console.log(output); //-> ' This is testing  hi'
```

Comment: I should not replace them with empty string, those tags have to be still present in the string but should not be considered for the count.  Because I need to display this in v-html (vuejs) as per proper tags. For better clarity I have added my filter function in the question

Comment: @MadasuK wondering if you got an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
const input = "<p> This is testing <strong> hi </strong> how are you, Well doing  </p>";
const count = input.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "").length;

console.log(count); // Output: 47
```